# Jumping Frog on even number of pads using DrRacket (Scheme)

Tags: math, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

**I am trying to solve this question below which first requires finding the math formula then writing code in DrRacket (Scheme dialect of Lisp):**

A frog with unlimited jumping power is sitting on the first pad (pad number 0), out of N pads in a row (N is always even). The frog wants to reach the last (Nth) pad. The frog can jump any even number of pads, including N: it’s possible that it will do it in 1 jump (by jumping N pads), in N/2 jumps (by jumping 2 pads at a time) or in any other combination of even jumps. For example, if N were 4, it could jump in one jump: 0th to 4th, or in 2 jumps (from 0th to 2nd and then from 2nd to 4th). The total number of ways of jumping from the 0th to the 4th pad is 2 ways.

- What is the math formula for finding the total number of ways the frog can reach the Nth pad?
- Using Scheme, write a procedure that, given a number of pads N, returns the total number of ways the frog can reach the Nth pad BY USING RECURSIVE CALLS ONLY. If the number of pad N is not even, the frog can't jump and the procedure returns "x".

---

**I got a solved question which is slightly different and here is the solution for it below, but I am not sure what the math formula is for the question above, though, so would appreciate your help.**

*A frog with unlimited jumping power is sitting on the first pad (pad number 1), out of N pads in a row. The frog wants to reach the last (Nth) pad. The frog can jump any number of pads, including N: it's possible that it will do it in 1 jump (by jumping N pads), in N jumps (by jumping 1 pad at a time) or in any other combination. For example, if N were 4, it could jump one jump; 1 to 4th, or in 2 jumps; the first of length 1 and then 2 (from 1st to 2nd and then from 2nd to 4th), or the first of length 2 and then 1 (from 1st to 3rd and then from 3rd to 4th), or in 3 jumps (from 1st to 2nd and from 2nd to 3rd and from 3rd to 4th). The total number of ways of jumping from the 1st to the 4th pad is 4 ways. Write a procedure that, given a number of pads N, returns the total number of ways the frog can reach the Nth pad.*

***Solution:***

- **Total possible jumps = 2 ^ (N-2)**
- DrRacket Code: `(define(pad-jumps n)(power 2 (- n 2))))`

Comment: How did you determine that the total number of possibilities for the simpler problem was `2^(N-2)`? Use the same tools you used for that simpler problem on this one, and then implementing that formula in Scheme will be easy.

Comment: @amalloy I don't think he solved the second one himself, it's something that was given to him.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I suspect that as well. In which case, my comment simplifies to "We're here to help with Scheme, not solve homework problems for you. Once you have the math solved, come back with a Scheme question if you still have one."

Comment: Is the only difference between the two problems that the first one starts from `0` instead of `1`, and the first frog can only jump an even number of pads?

Comment: If that's the case, then I think the two problems are essentially the same, the numbers are simply doubled. So divide N by 2 and use the other solution.